# Why if the set of values of the sequence terms is finite then the sequence is eventually a constant?

Tags: proof-explanation, cauchy-sequences

I am reading a proof of theorem that states that the sequence is Cauchy only if it's convergent. At the beginning of the proof it is stated that if the set of the values of sequence is finite then the sequence is ultimately a constant so from there it is convergent as well. For example a sequence ${(-1)^n}$ forms a finite set of values, but for a sequence to be Cauchy, shouldn't inequality $|a_n-a_m|<\epsilon$ be true for whatever epsilon? I don't see how this sequence is ultimately constant it if every second term is opposite of the first one.

Comment: I believe they mean that such a sequence is eventually constant if it is Cauchy. Of course $(-1)^n$ is not Cauchy.

Comment: Are you certain that they don't state, in some form or another, that a _Cauchy_ sequence that only takes finitely many different values is eventually constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are sequences with only finitely many values that aren't eventually constant, as $(-1)^n$ shows.

But *Cauchy sequences* with only finitely many values are eventually constant. Indeed let $(u_n)$ be such a Cauchy sequence and let $x_1,...,x_k$ be the values it takes, we take the $x_i$ to be distinct. Let $e= \min_{i\neq j} |x_i-x_j|>0$ and $\epsilon = e/2$.

Then by Cauchy-ness, there is $N$ such that for $n,m\geq N$, $|u_n-u_m|<\epsilon$.

Let $i$ be such that $u_N = x_i$. Then for $n\geq N$, $|u_n - u_N|< \epsilon < e$. Let $k$ be such that $u_n = x_k$. Then if $k\neq i$, $|u_n-u_N| = |x_k-x_i| \geq e > |u_n-u_N|$, a contradiction. Therefore $x_k = x_i$. Therefore for all $n\geq N, u_n = x_i$ : $(u_n)$ is eventually constant.

Comment: I have a question: Why if $k\neq i, |u_n-i_N|=|x_k-x_i|$? Is it only because $e$ is larger than $\epsilon$? Because $e$ is defined as minimum distance between two different values and then it seems like $|x_k-x_i|=e$ only because it must be smaller than epsilon, but then it must be larger than e. I just don't see where the equality $e=|x_k-x_i|$ is coming from.

Comment: For the first question it's just because $u_n = x_k$ and $u_N = x_i$. For the second question, the equality was a typo, I meant $\geq$, not $=$.

Comment: I think the direct proof is clearly. 

Lets suppose everything up to the fact that $\forall n,m \geqslant N$, $|u_n - u_m| < \epsilon$. 

Since $e$ is the minimum difference which is positive because all points on the range of the sequence are different, then $|u_n - u_m| < \epsilon$ happens iif $u_n = u_m$, $\forall n,m \geqslant N$. 

Then, $\forall k \geqslant N$, it exists $u_0$ in the range of the sequence such that $u_k = u_0$, which is the definition of the constant sequence.